# Best way to update values for views in activity from any class with Kotlin in android 4.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, class, kotlin, android-activity

I'm trying to update values in a TextView from an external class but not work, I'm trying with many ways y many posts but unlucky me... BTW sent the TextView like a parameter in class and works but we know that not is the best way if I have many views.

So first with a basic code:

In Main Activity XML:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

In code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        ClaseDePrueba(this@MainActivity)
    }
}
```

Finally in class with my last proof

```
class ClaseDePrueba(ctx : Context)
{
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null,false)
    view.tvHello.text = "New Value"
}
```

Even I try to use the Kotlin android extensions like this web site but not work for me

https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*
```

A few hours ago I tried to implement an interface but I don't know how to reference the TextView and chance value, my code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() , ClaseDePrueba.MyInterfaceClass {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ClaseDePrueba(this@MainActivity)

    }

    override fun updateClass() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
```

And my class

```
class ClaseDePrueba(ctx: Context)
{

    interface MyInterfaceClass {
        fun updateClass(
        )
    }
```

**So the question is... What is the (best) way to fix and do it work correctly?**

**UPDATE and one solution**

well I solved created a list of objects and pass as a parameter

I don't know if is the best way but at the moment works thanks all

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() , ClaseDePrueba.MyInterfaceClass {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val textViews = ArrayList<TextView>()
        textViews.add(tvHello)
        textViews.add(tvHello2)

        ClaseDePrueba(this@MainActivity, textViews)

    }
```

```
class ClaseDePrueba(ctx: Context, private val tviews: ArrayList<TextView>? = null)
{
    init {
        if (tviews != null) {
            tviews[0].text = "Init1"
            tviews[1].text = "Init2"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Views within activity should be manipulated within activity. There is no reason for inflating them outside the activity class. Why can't you put `tvHello.text = "New Value"` directly in the activity?

Comment: This code is an example, but I have a complex code with a class and functions like "override fun onSuccess" and more, and then I need to show the results in the activity

Comment: Then create an interface, implement it in your activity and trigger it from wherever you want e.g from onSuccess, your activity will be listening to it.

Comment: sorry I tried but not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an `Activity`, and it inflates a layout, it creates the objects in the XML and assigns them IDs. The XML is like a recipe, the Activity is the cook, baking a delicious view layout.

So your `Activity` has some `TextView` objects. If you have another class, and that inflates the same XML file, it creates **different objects**. It's baking its own layout, and any changes you make to those `View` objects won't be seen in the `Activity`, because it has a completely different set of `TextView` instances (which happen to share ID values, because that's what the XML recipe says)

So if you want to mess with those `TextView`s in the `Activity`, you have three basic options:

- have the `Activity` pass them to the other class, in a collection like a list. ("Here you are, here's the stuff you need to work with")
- make them publicly accessible in the `Activity`, so you can pass the `Activity` instance to your other class, and it can poke them directly e.g. `myActivity.coolTextView1.text = "wow!"`
- make some kind of interface on the `Activity`, e.g. `fun updateText(id: Int, text: String)` which the other class can call when it needs to update something. The `Activity` handles the details internally, like finding the relevant `TextView` object and updating it

either way, if you want to change those specific `TextView` instances displayed in your `Activity`, you need to access those instances somehow

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Interface and try to implement it in your activity.
`interface MyInterface { fun update() }`
Then try to access the function with the reference of class.

```
`Class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() ,MyInterface{
  override fun update(){
  }
    }'
```

Access this function with class reference and update the value.

Comment: I'll try with an interface and I let you know

Comment: Sorry, but isn't clear to me how to use an interface to update a value in a class to reflect that value in a TextView. ie how "Access this function with class reference and update the value." your last line

Comment: This is my main activity:

`class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() , ClaseDePrueba.MyInterfaceClass {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ClaseDePrueba(this@MainActivity)

    }

    override fun updateClass() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }`

and my class

`class ClaseDePrueba(ctx: Context)
{

    interface MyInterfaceClass {
        fun updateClass(
        )
    }`

but I don't know how to implement code
Can you help me?

Comment: I hope that can help
    `class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), UpdateUi {
    lateinit var updateUi: UpdateUi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        updateUi=this
        var obj=A(updateUi)
    }

    override fun updateUi(text: String) {
        textView.text=text
    }

}

interface UpdateUi {
     fun updateUi(text:String)
}

class A( private val updateUiImp: UpdateUi) {
    fun update(){
        updateUiImp.updateUi("HI")
    }
    
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing,

```
class ClaseDePrueba(ctx : Context)
{
    val txtView : TextView = (ctx as MainActivity).findViewById(R.id.tvHello) as TextView 
    txtView.setText("Hello")
}
```

(No need to inflate layout again)
The other way could be to implement an Interface

Comment: Sorry I tried but didn't work, there is an error in the second line says "Expecting member declaration" I suppose that happens because of the different syntax  between Java-Kotlin